# Standard location to put jar files for command line java programs

Tags: java, jar, path

Several developers have created stand alone java command line programs. These programs share libraries, such as sql server jar. What is the preferred or standard location these shared external jar files be placed according to convention?

- /usr/local/lib
- /opt
- /var/lib

Comment: Sound more like a OS distribution question

Comment: Depends on flavor of Linux. Different distributions have different recommended locations for user code.

Answer (score 0):

The location doesn't matter as much as standardizing the location. Another solution would be to use a dependency management system like Maven and package the dependencies in the jar. However, this would be inefficient if you are reusing the jars across multiple projects but it does ensure that the dependencies are present and isn't susceptible to someone swapping the version of the dependency in the shared folder with a newer version that breaks other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides several ways to manage class and library loading, but looking for one location based on the OS is not something that is in line with keeping Java platform independent. Instead try defining a common location for your project based on [how Java finds classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html).

Also, if you are executing your command line app from jars, Maven has some nice plugins to help [bundle your java classes as an executable jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). It is much cleaner and encapsulates the libraries within the scope of your individual applications.